# In order to improve the java app performance, how could I perform batch execution in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, batch-processing

We want to store a certain amount of user requests into a queue and when it comes up to a certain amount like 20 or a certain amount of time has gone, it will automatically make a batch execute in java.

The batch operations like batch insert into a MySQL db to avoid single insert every request comes.

Comment: You mean to cellect certain type of request and to the all at once instead of one at a time?

Comment: yeah, we want to use a queue to store user requests and flush out all the requests at once, and the queue will store the next incoming requests.

Answer (score 0):

I would encapsulate that functionality in a class BatchCollector. BatchCollector would accept requests and store them in a private queue. When accepting a request it would check the queue size and store the request or flush all requests to the database. Make the public methods of BatchCollector synchronized, add a flush and a close method (implementing AutoCloseable). Similar structure as BufferedOutputStream.

Following a simple example. The example uses "synchronized", you can replace that with ReentrantLock (see [synchronized-vs-reentrantlock-on-performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600520/synchronized-vs-reentrantlock-on-performance)). Probably more important would be a concurrent execution of the batch. This can be done inside batchHandler, using a thread-safe queue of batches feeding a separate batch execution thread.

```
public final class BatchCollector<R> implements Consumer<R>, AutoCloseable {

private final Queue<R> queue = new LinkedList<>();
private final int capacity;
private final Consumer<List<R>> batchHandler;

private boolean closed;

public BatchCollector(Consumer<List<R>> batchHandler, int capacity) {
    this.batchHandler = batchHandler;
    this.capacity = capacity;
}

@Override
public synchronized void accept(R request) {
    if (closed) throw new IllegalStateException("Closed.");
    queue.add(request);
    if (queue.size() == capacity) flush();
}

public synchronized void flush() {
    if (closed) throw new IllegalStateException("Closed.");
    List<R> batch = new ArrayList<>(queue);
    queue.clear();
    batchHandler.accept(batch);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() throws Exception {
    if(!closed) flush();
    closed = true;
}

}
```

Comment: Making the method synchronized is not what we want though it will slow down the concurrent performance. Would you show me the codes to implement the function, thanks.

Comment: I would check if it is really a performance issue. If so, take a thread safe queue internally and pay attention to the "closed" state in respect to thread-safety, too. Sorry, currently I have not the time for an example. Maybe later.

Answer (score 0):

Consider these interfaces I just made up.
Firstly, implement this one to accept user requests:

```
public interface BatchCollector {
  public void accept(UserRequest request);
  public void setBatchExecutor(BatchExecutor exec);
}
```

And then this one, to specify the batch processing:

```
public interface BatchExecutor {      
  public void execute(List<UserRequest> requests);
}
```

The implementing classes would neatly encapsulate all the logic required to accept requests and to trigger execution of a batch of requests. Exactly when to trigger execution would be up to the `BatchCollector`, and how to perform the execution would be up to the `BatchExecutor`

Comment: thanks for the comment, but the interfaces above are not enough because we have to handle the concurrent threads problems and have to find out how to trigger the execution of batch requests, we want to keep the queue alive when flush out all the requests and it will store the incoming requests later